# Powershell script to set AD permissions fails with "Access Denied" despite running account having the correct permissions

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I'm using the following Powershell cmdlet as part of a script:

```
# Posted by TobyU at www.pwsh.ch on 13.09.2018
# https://www.pwsh.ch/active-directory-powershell-delegate-permission-to-reset-user-passwords-for-a-specific-organizational-unit-150.html

function Set-ResetPasswordDelegation(){
    param(
    [string]$OrganizationalUnit,
    [string]$DelegationGroupName
    )

    # Configuration Parameters
    $confADRight = "ExtendedRight"
    $confDelegatedObjectType = "bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2" # User Object Type GUID
    $confExtendedRight = "00299570-246d-11d0-a768-00aa006e0529" # Extended Right PasswordReset GUID

    # Collect and prepare Objects
    $delegationGroup = Get-ADGroup -Identity $DelegationGroupName
    $delegationGroupSID = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier] $delegationGroup.SID
    $delegationGroupACL = Get-Acl -Path "AD:\$OrganizationalUnit"

    # Build Access Control Entry (ACE)
    $aceIdentity = [System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference] $delegationGroupSID
    $aceADRight = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights] $confADRight
    $aceType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType] "Allow"
    $aceInheritanceType = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurityInheritance] "Descendents"
    $ace = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule($aceIdentity, $aceADRight, $aceType, $confExtendedRight, $aceInheritanceType,$confDelegatedObjectType)

    # Apply ACL
    $delegationGroupACL.AddAccessRule($ace)
    Set-Acl -Path "AD:\$OrganizationalUnit" -AclObject $delegationGroupACL
}
```

To summarize, the script above is intended to delegate password reset permissions, so that a certain security group (DelegationGroupName parameter) is allowed to reset passwords for all users inside a certain OU (OrganisationalUnit parameter).

This works fine when run as an administrator, but when I try to run it as an account that I use to run scheduled tasks, I run into a problem. See below:

```
PS D:\Program\ocpermissions> Set-ResetPasswordDelegation -OrganizationalUnit 'OU=Test,OU=ITA,DC=kos,DC=local' 'Test PW Reset Group'
Set-Acl : This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object
At D:\Program\ocpermissions\PasswordResetDelegation.psm1:29 char:5
+     Set-Acl -Path "AD:\$OrganizationalUnit" -AclObject $delegationGro ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (OU=Test,OU=ITA,DC=kos,DC=local:St
   ring) [Set-Acl], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ADProvider:SetSecurityDescriptor:ADError,Microso
   ft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

This is despite the fact that I have given the user that the script is running to full control to the OU and all objects in it. (Just for testing purposes.) I also can't see that the code is trying to change the owner of the OU either, so that confuses me even more.

[image: Screenshot showing that the svc-ocpermissions account has Full Control permissions on the Test OU]

Strangely, I don't even get the same thing in my actual production OU when testing this, Instead I get this:

```
Set-Acl : Access is denied
At D:\Program\ocpermissions\PasswordResetDelegation.psm1:29 char:5
+     Set-Acl -Path "AD:\$OrganizationalUnit" -AclObject $delegationGro ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (OU=Externa anvä...DC=kos,DC=l
   ocal:String) [Set-Acl], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ADProvider:SetSecurityDescriptor:AccessDenied,Mi
   crosoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

What could be going on? What could be stopping the script from working correctly? (I should add that the script works fine with an account having Domain Admin privileges, but I really don't want to run a scheduled task with under those permissions.)

Comment: Accept your answer as the correct answer, you'll get a badge for it  :-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `Set-Acl` doesn't work correctly in this context. Not sure exactly what was wrong with it, but when instead using `Set-ADOrganizationalUnit $ou -Replace @{nTSecurityDescriptor = $ouacl}` to set the ACL, the problem disappeared.

That tells me the problem wasn't with AD permissions as I originally suspected.

Here's the fixed version of the function I was trying to use:

```
function Set-ResetPasswordDelegation(){
    param(
    [string]$OrganizationalUnit,
    [string]$DelegationGroupName
    )

    # Configuration Parameters
    $confADRight = "ExtendedRight"
    $confDelegatedObjectType = "bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2" # User Object Type GUID
    $confExtendedRight = "00299570-246d-11d0-a768-00aa006e0529" # Extended Right PasswordReset GUID

    # Collect and prepare Objects
    $delegationGroup = Get-ADGroup -Identity $DelegationGroupName
    $delegationGroupSID = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier] $delegationGroup.SID
    $ou = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Properties nTSecurityDescriptor $OrganizationalUnit
    $ouacl = $OU.nTSecurityDescriptor

    # Build Access Control Entry (ACE)
    $aceIdentity = [System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference] $delegationGroupSID
    $aceADRight = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights] $confADRight
    $aceType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType] "Allow"
    $aceInheritanceType = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurityInheritance] "Descendents"
    $ace = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule($aceIdentity, $aceADRight, $aceType, $confExtendedRight, $aceInheritanceType,$confDelegatedObjectType)

    # Apply ACL
    $ouacl.AddAccessRule($ace)
    Set-ADOrganizationalUnit $ou -Replace @{nTSecurityDescriptor = $ouacl}
}
```